# Forcing python function parameters to not have order

Tags: python, function, arguments, keyword-argument

I have a python function that takes a large amount of parameters :

```
def func(p1=0, p2=0, p3=0, p4=0, p5=0, ..., pN=0) -> None: pass
```

I wanted to force the user to set the parameters as keyword arguments.

I thought about one solution that seems off to me:

```
def func(*_, p1=0, p2=0, p3=0, p4=0, p5=0, ..., pN=0) -> None: pass
```

I can even raise an error if unwanted ordered arguments were given and even separate ordered arguments from unordered arguments:

```
def func(p1, p2, p3, *unwanted, p4=0, p5=0, p6=0, ..., pN=0) -> None:
    if unwanted: raise TypeError
```

I haven't seen anyone do this, is there a problem with this?

Comment: I am not quite sure whether I understood the question, but try `func(p1, p2, p3, *, p4=0, ..., pN=0)`

Comment: You don't actually need the `_`; `*` alone is sufficient to mark the "boundary" between ordinary parameters and keyword-only parameters. (`*_` is the same as `*args`: it's a parameter named `_` that gathers any positional arguments not assigned to other parameters. It can *also* mark the boundary between ordinary and keyword-only parameters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already a standard method. It is defined in [PEP3102](https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/)

It's used in many libraries.

To give you one example: in [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)' [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) function, all parameters after `*` are keywords only:

```
DataFrame.drop(labels=None, *, axis=0, index=None, columns=None, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')
```

Note that you don't need the `_` if you just want to ignore the parameters, a bare `*` is sufficient.